# How can I add a trigger at scroll position to an angular controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scroll, window

I'm trying to create a nav menu where when you scroll to a section the "selected" navigation changes. I'm using JQuery for the scroll triggers, but I can't seem to call $(window) from inside the controller. I have a nav specific controller which binds a variable "selected" to which nav is selected. So I'm not sure how I should go about building. Essentially I need to access my nav.selected in the controller, but I seem to need to be outside of the controller in order to use $(window) in jquery...

Could someone give me an explanation on how I may go about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using angularJS window provider?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

It should allow you to use window javascript object inside angular.